# Improve system performance with all my extra RAM?

Tags: linux

I have a massive amount of RAM on my home server (32 Gig).  Is there something I can do to make my Linux system extremely fast with it, such as put the root FS in a RAM disk at boot somehow?

Comment: 32 GB isn't even close to a "massive amount of RAM" these days.  ;-)  Linux is good at using extra RAM for caching anyway so I think you won't see a lot of improvement for your work.

Comment: I have a Linux VM with 512MB of RAM and the app it hosts is blazing fast.  Maybe you're doing it wrong?  (translation: "extremely fast" means nothing to us until you state an actual issue or gives us hard data to work with)...oh and Off-Topic for ServerFault.

Comment: Yeah. Come back when you have 521gb or more when you want to call it Massive. In fact, 32gb is not even the top line for a MICRO ATX WORKSTATION BOARD ;) Have one here with 64gb. And regarding performance - you expect your extra RAM to make the CPU faster? Magic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing disk space and RAM. This is totally different, both exist for different purposes.

To answer your question: If you mount the root fs in a ram disk the write operations won't be reflected so that's a bit pointless.

If you use your system intensively enough, Linux will naturally fill up the system cache so there's basically nothing to do.

Nevertheless here are some tips that I would do if I had RAM:

- Disable [swapiness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swappiness)
- Mount temporary folders like [/tmp in RAM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173094/how-can-i-use-ram-storage-for-the-tmp-directory-and-how-to-set-a-maximum-amount)

More to read:

- [Tuning swapiness](http://archive.is/FKlQ)
- [Linux ate my RAM](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/)

Comment: Thanks, I understand that RAM is volatile.  My idea was to load the FS to RAM at boot, then unload to disk at shutdown.  I also like the other guy's answer about the virtual machine in RAM.  The two downvotes are why I never use this site.  Thanks SamK.

Comment: @user206442 Linux will already do that, except it will do it if and only if it's the best use of that RAM.